# Disable href on last item

Tags: jquery

I have a tab show / hide system which works but I need to remove the href from the click event when it reaches the final "tab"

Demo [here](http://wpthemes4u.co.uk/demo/zien-html/)

Scroll down to the "popular, recent top reviews" section and click the + icon on the far right, it will change the images (there are 3 "tabs" and it doesn't stop at the last one, it displays a blank area

JS

```
$('#popular .next').click(function() {
  $('#popular .current')
      .removeClass('current')
      .hide()
      .next()
      .show()
      .addClass('current');
  if ( $('.current').hasClass('last') ) {
      $('#popular .next').removeAttr('href');
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to unbind click event not remove href. See my working demo and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263946/disable-href-on-last-item/24264076#24264076)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/2Y7Ww/1/)**

It is not necessary to remove `href`, you need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) `click` event from your plus link like;

```
$('#popular .next').click(function() {
  $('#popular .current').removeClass('current').hide()
  .next().show().addClass('current');
  if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
   $(this).unbind('click');
  }
 });
```

Comment: Perfecto, I had an unbind on one of the other tabs which didn't work but changing to $(this) worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any href attribute, but from what I see you need to remove the click handler.

```
if ( $('.current').hasClass('last') ) {
    $(this).off('click');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or **[`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** as there is no href attribute.

```
$('#popular .next').click(function() {
    $('#popular .current')
        .removeClass('current')
        .hide()
        .next()
        .show()
        .addClass('current');

    if ($('.current').attr('id') === 'tab3') {
        $(this).unbind('click');
    }
});
```